# JSF/Primefaces: How to trigger this form submit programmatically (need to bypass submission until things validate)

Tags: forms, validation, jsf, primefaces

What I'm trying to do is validate specific fields **before the form submission**.

These fields already get blur validation, which works great if you **tab** through all the fields because as you tab out, you fire that field's blur event. The problem comes when you don't tab out of the last field, for example, you mouse to the "save" button.  When you click the "save" button, you are blurring/validating that field, but you're also submitting the form.  **I need to validate before this submission**.

The form is a little different than regular forms in that it has inline editing involved.  It's on a confirmation page from a wizard-type of flow where the user can submit their previously entered info or edit it before they submit (without going back to previous steps).  Here's a screenshot that hopefully illustrates this, https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG4kH.jpg

Here is a a sample input:

```
<h:outputLabel for="registrationReEnterNewPassword2" value="Confirm new password" />
<p:password
    forceId="true" autocomplete="off" id="registrationReEnterNewPassword2" 
    value="#{backingBean.user.newPasswordAgain}" maxlength="15" size="26"
    valueChangeListener="#{backingBean.passwordValueChangeListener}" 
    tabindex="5" styleClass="inputText"
    binding="#{backingBean.passwordUI}">    
    <f:attribute name="currentPassword" value="#{registrationExistingPassword2.value}" />                           
    <f:attribute name="newPassword" value="#{registrationNewPassword2.value}" />
    <f:validator validatorId="ConfirmPasswordValidator"/>
    <f:ajax event="blur"
        execute="registrationNewPassword2 registrationReEnterNewPassword2"
        render="message_passwordB1 message_passwordB2" />
</p:password>
<p:message id="message_passwordB2" styleClass="errorMessage" for="registrationReEnterNewPassword2"/>
```

Here is the "save" button for this section of the form:

```
<p:commandButton
    value="Save" 
    type="submit"
    styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only a4jhover"
    onclick="waitingModal();"
    oncomplete="closeWaitingModal(); closeEditPane();"
    onerror="closeWaitingModal();"
    rendered="#{Context.User.registered}"
    action="#{backingBean.submit}"
    update=":messagesForm:messageContent:messages">
</p:commandButton>
```

Does anyone know how I can trigger the validations on each form's "section" when that section's "save" button is clicked?

Comment: Are you using JPA/BeanValidation annotations?

Comment: I don't even know what those are (I'm a front-end developer), so probably not.  The validation works fine on blurs, but when you blur by clicking the "save" button, you get a bit of a race condition (blur event -vs- form submission).

Comment: Your question is sound, but I'm not sure how exactly this forms a problem. What exactly is (not) happening when you immediately mouse to the save button instead of tabbing to it? It should surely also execute the validation regardless of how it was submitted.

Comment: It does validate (clicking the save button blurs the text field), but that also submits the form (the form submits while the validation is happening).  I want to delay the form submission based on any validation errors. If there are validation errors, don't submit, if there are no validation errors, submit.

Comment: But if there are validation errors, then the action method should already not be invoked at all. I do therefore still not understand the concrete problem. Is it that the validation messages behave weird as in completely disappearing or so? You're namely re-rendering them on complete of the ajax submit. By the way, please use `@nickname` to trigger a comment-reply notification when more than one people have posted a comment on your post. I wasn't notified about your last comment.

Comment: @BalusC I think the issue is a race condition?  If you enter text in the last text field and move your mouse to the "save" button (while that text field still has focus), then click the "save" button, you trigger the blur validation but you also submit the form before the validation returns.  You have two things happening.  Does that make sense?

Comment: As far as I know, the submit won't work if there are validation errors. That's bundled in JSF itself.